# Bootstrap layout advice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Example layout]

I have found myself fumbling around with this odd layout that I need to design using Bootstrap.

Imagine the size of this is 660 x 330 wide, What I want to do is without any padding between anything is have an image on the left side that fills the black color 100%. The size of this will never change, on screens that it doesn't fit it will be using a different layout (so this will only really be on small+ screen sizes.

Here is what I originally was thinking, but since the image doesn't necessarily fit a column width, this will not work. Would it be best to create a container that is exactly 660x330 and then use rows/columns inside that? Or maybe I should step away from bootstrap in this case.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="../images/temp-featurelarge.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a div with specific Width and Height and then use columns to split. But here in your case I guess if you use "width: 50%" for the inner divs that would be fine and it's not necessary to use Bootstrap columns.

Comment: That is awesome, i'm going to try this out, because the big thing I can't have happen is the image in the left section change width or height.

Answer (score 0):

View my demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/tnu6to7z/1/)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="left">
        asdfdasf
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 no_padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 no_padding">
            <div class="right_top">
                 asfjldfj
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 no_padding">
            <div class="bottom_left">Dfdsaf</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no_padding">
            <div class="bottom_right">Dfdsaf</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css=============>

```
body{
    color:#FFF;
}
.left{
    background:black;
    height:300px;
}
.right_top{
    background:red;
    height:150px;
}
.bottom_left{
    background:pink;
    height:150px;
}
.no_padding{
    padding:0;
}
.bottom_right{
    background:blue;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking, the problem is I don't want it to change aspect ration when resizing the browser window.  Its kinda hard to explain, so checkout your edited fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/maddogawl/tnu6to7z/2/